How to get real-time buffer count value?
I'm writing code to output the Width, Height, and Real-time buffer count value of a live image from a Basler camera.
I was successful in outputting the Width, Height values.
On the other hand,I'm struggling to write codes which shows the real-time buffer count.
This is what I wrote.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "imageviewer12.h"
#include "imageviewer12Dlg.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"

void Cimageviewer12Dlg::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    CString strX;
    strX.Format(_T("X: %d"), point.x);

    CString strY;
    strY.Format(_T("Y: %d"), point.y);


    SetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT1, strX); 
    SetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT2, strY); 

    CDialogEx::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
}


It works as I intended. However, the code I found while searching is this.
: if (ptrGrabResult->GrabSucceeded())
            { }
                // Access the image data.
                cout << “SizeX: ” << ptrGrabResult->GetWidth() << endl;
                cout << “SizeY: ” << ptrGrabResult->GetHeight() << endl;
                const uint8_t* pImageBuffer = (uint8_t*) ptrGrabResult->GetBuffer();
                cout << “Gray value of first pixel: ” << (uint32_t) pImageBuffer[0] << endl << endl;

Is this the code I should utilize to display the buffer value?
Even so, But I still want to keep what I wrote about width and height. Is there a way?

The two code samples seem to be unrelated. The first one is about showing the coordinates of a mouse, only the second is showing information about an image.

I guess the question is why you think the first piece of code is showing you anything about an image from a camera (and not showing you the coordinates of the mouse)?

Technically, they're not the same thing. but if I know the mouse coordinates, I know the coordinates of the image when I hover over it. @john

It's hard to answer without knowing much about your knowledge of C++ or about the rest of your code. For example in your current code do you have a variable called ptrGrabResult? If you do have this variable then what happens if you replace point.x with ptrGrabResult->GetWidth()? If you don't have this variable then what do you know about declaring it and correctly initialising it?

I'll have to think about it a bit more, but thanks for the reply. @john

@Sangheyeon Woo, Slightly late to the party, I presume you'd like to display coordinates of mouse over camera image displayed on the screen, correct? What is your operating system? I'm asking bcs there are some pylon SDK helpers to get flawlessly through these grab buffers and convert them to GDI compliant format.

I used a workaround to get the camera coordinates regardless of the image. Yes, I'm using the SDK.
